# WPF и MessageBox в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Имеется приложение WPF, служит для дозирования жидкостей. При каждом новом дозировании необходимо проверить, сменилась ли емкость под дозатором, и если нет, то вывести сообщение о необходимости смены емкости. Есть такой код

```
    public bool CheckChangeCupInThread()
    {
        if (_dispenser.Status.CupChanged == DispenserEnums.CupChanged.False)
        {
            var cupFormThread = new ThreadStart(CupWaitChangeForm);
            var cupFormWaiter = new Thread(cupFormThread) {IsBackground = true};
            cupFormWaiter.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            var cupThread = new ThreadStart(WaitForCupChange);
            var cupWaiter = new Thread(cupThread) {IsBackground = true};
            cupWaiter.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            cupFormWaiter.Start();
            cupWaiter.Start();

            do
            {
                //Wait for Cup to be changed or Cancel
            } while (cupFormWaiter.IsAlive && cupWaiter.IsAlive);

            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            if (cupFormWaiter.IsAlive)
            {
                cupFormWaiter.Abort();
                cupFormWaiter.Join();
            }
            if (cupWaiter.IsAlive)
            {
                _dispenser.SurveillanceWorker.Continue = false;
                cupWaiter.Join(200);
                return false;
            }
            watch.Stop();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void WaitForCupChange()
    {
        do
        {
            _dispenser.GetStatus();
        } while (_dispenser.Status.CupChanged == DispenserEnums.CupChanged.False);
    }

    private void CupWaitChangeForm()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Change please the cup", "Cup сhange", MessageBoxButtons.Cancel);
    }
```

здесь _dispenser собственно и есть дозатор. Принцип такой: или емкость сменили, или клавишу "Отмена" в MessageBox нажали, потоки завершаются с соответствующим результатом. Все вроде нормально на первый взгляд. Но очень часто этот код приводит к аварийному завершению работы программы. 
Пробовал сделать тоже самое с тасками, но как-то не очень получилось, в многопоточных приложениях я новичок.
Работаю с WPF и паттерном MVVM.

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: Вы хотите переделать код с использованием `Task`? Или что?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как избавиться от вот этого аварийного завершения программы. Я не знаю, как лучше с Таском, или без. У меня проблема с тем, что программа вылетает

Comment: Покажите Вашу ошибку, приведённый код с виду исключений генерировать не должен, нужно разбираться.

Comment: Ну что за жесть... Зачем два потока, `SetApartmentState`, пустой цикл, повторная проверка на `IsAlive`?

Comment: `Thread.Abort` — опасный вызов, его применять нельзя, если вы не на все сто процентов понимаете возможные проблемы. Это может быть причиной плохого поведения. Опишите лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Я вроде описал уже. При новом дозировании нужно сменить емкость под дозатором. Там есть сенсор, который реагирует на смену емкости и выставляет соответствующий флаг в "истину". Вот если этот флаг "ложь", нужно вывести сообщение на экран "Смените емкость" с кнопкой "Отмена", которое должно исчезнуть с экрана при смене емкости, или при нажатии на кнопку "Отмена" должен прекратиться процесс дозирования.

Comment: To Raider: Я понимаю, что код не очень, но это унаследованная система, код написан лет 5 назад и не мной, а тот кто писал, давно уже не работает на фирме.
Я как раз пытаюсь все это в порядок привести, Самое смешное, что раньше этот код находился в классе с более, чем 4000 строк кода и нормально работал. Теперь я это растащил по разным классам и происходит крах системы, причем сообщение системное "Аварийное завершение программы" и какая причина, непонятно. Еще одна странность не на всех компьютерах.

Comment: To VladD: Понимаю, что Thread.Abort - опасный вызов, но, как я уже писал, не очень хорошо соображаю в многопоточности, поэтому мои попытки написать что-то более приличное, ни к чему не привели. Обычно все примеры в Инете написаны для консольных приложений и в тестовых приложениях, как правило, все работает. Но у меня WPF система и видимо основная причина в этом. Что-то связанное с основным потоком программы. Т.е. реальное завершение задачи происходит тогда, когда я уже покидаю этот процесс, и из-за этого крах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение своей проблемы. Теперь MessageBox закрвыается, если заканчивается Task1, или Task1 прерывается, если нажата кнопка "Cancel" в MessageBox

```
internal class Program
{
    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                i++;
            } while (i < 10);
            Console.WriteLine("t1 has been finished");
        };

        Action<object> action1 = (object obj) =>
        {
            DialogResult result = DialogResult.OK;
            do
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show("This is task2", "Task2", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            } while (result != DialogResult.Cancel);
            Console.WriteLine("t2 has been finished");
        };

        var tasks = new Task[2];
        var source1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token1 = source1.Token;
        Task t1 = new Task(action, "alpha", token1);
        tasks[0] = t1;
        Task t2 = new Task(action1, "betha");
        tasks[1] = t2;

        t1.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("t1 has been launched. (Main Thread={0})",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        t2.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("t2 has been launched. (Main Thread={0})",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        try
        {
            int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
            if (t1.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                source1.Cancel();
            if (t2.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                CloseMessage();
            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} completed first.\n", tasks[index].Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Status of all tasks:");
            foreach (var t in tasks)
                Console.WriteLine("   Task #{0}: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
        }
        catch (AggregateException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CloseMessage()
    {
        int window = FindWindow(null, "Task2");
        if (window != 0)
            SendMessage(window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
    }
}
```